# avoid loading images using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, loading

Say I have the following code in my html:

```
<html>
  <....> 
   <img src="the-image.gif" />
  <....>
</html>
```

Is it possible to avoid loading the image using javascript? I want to load it later, using javascript. But I don't want it to be loaded automatically.

I am trying to delay the request of the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [LazyLoad jQuery Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

> Lazy loader is a jQuery plugin written
>   in JavaScript. It delays loading of
>   images in (long) web pages. Images
>   outside of viewport (visible part of
>   web page) wont be loaded before user
>   scrolls to them. This is opposite of
>   image preloading.